# Can anyone tell me how can i add more than 50 subdomains in AWS AMPLIFY?

Tags: amazon-web-services, subdomain, devops, aws-amplify, amazon-route53

Can anyone tell me how can i add more subdomains in AWS AMPLIFY? It has max hard limit of 50 subdomains per app. I am going to add 1000s of subdomains. i need to kee[p amplify working and add subdomains. i cant add just cname in route53. cname can't work because those cnames are related to cloudfront and cloudfronts are being managed by amplify itself.if i add subdomain in Amplify then amplify gives instructions to cloudfront and then it works. Otherwise it won't if i manually add subdomain in route53 only

Answer (score 1):

Note that the limitation of 50 subdomains is specific to `within the current region`

- https://docs.amazonaws.cn/en_us/general/latest/gr/amplify.html

However, the FAQ for Amazon Route 53 states:

- "Q. Is there a limit to the number of hosted zones I can manage using Amazon Route 53?"
- "Each Amazon Route 53 account is limited to a maximum of 500 hosted zones and 10,000 resource record sets per hosted zone"

Also see:

- "Q. Can I create multiple hosted zones for the same domain name?"
- "Yes. Creating multiple hosted zones allows you to verify your DNS setting in a “test” environment, and then replicate those settings on a “production” hosted zone. For example, hosted zone Z1234 might be your test version of example.com, hosted on name servers ns-1, ns-2, ns-3, and ns-4. Similarly, hosted zone Z5678 might be your production version of example.com, hosted on ns-5, ns-6, ns-7, and ns-8. Since each hosted zone has a virtual set of name servers associated with that zone, Route 53 will answer DNS queries for example.com differently depending on which name server you send the DNS query to."

**Routing traffic for subdomains**

- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/dns-routing-traffic-for-subdomains.html
- Create a hosted zone for the subdomain, and create records in the new hosted zone
- "You can also create a hosted zone for the subdomain. Using a separate hosted zone to route internet traffic for a subdomain is sometimes known as "delegating responsibility for a subdomain to a hosted zone" or "delegating a subdomain to other name servers" or some similar combination of terms."
- "Using a separate hosted zone for a subdomain also allows you to use different DNS services for the domain and the subdomain."
- "One way to route traffic for a subdomain is to create a hosted zone for the subdomain, and then create records for the subdomain in the new hosted zone. (The more common option is to create records for the subdomain in the hosted zone for the domain.)"
- "To define how you want Route 53 to route traffic for the subdomain (acme.example.com) and its subdomains (backend.acme.example.com), you create records in the hosted zone for the subdomain."

**Routing traffic for additional levels of subdomains**

- "You route traffic to a subdomain of a subdomain, such as backend.acme.example.com, the same way that you route traffic to a subdomain, such as acme.example.com. Either you create records in the hosted zone for the domain, or you create a hosted zone for the lower-level subdomain, and then you create records in that new hosted zone. "
- "If you choose to create a separate hosted zone for the lower-level subdomain, create the NS record for the lower-level subdomain in the hosted zone for the subdomain that is one level closer to the domain name. This helps to ensure that traffic is correctly routed to your resources."